# Query NIC sending buffer in Linux Kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, nic

Is there a way to query whether the sending buffer of on NIC card is full or not in Linux Kernel? I don't mean the buffer size, I mean the usage of the buffer.

THanks

Comment: In code, or from the command line? If the latter, try superuser.com

Comment: Sounds like a feature that would, if at all, be implemented by the network driver for a particular NIC. Check the driver documentation (or source) for the NIC; there could be a a function of some sort (probably ioctl(2)) or a proc / sysfs pseudo-file which can give you this info. Again, this is probably very specific to a NIC/driver.